# Display data on fast scroll bar android

Tags: android

as per my requirement, I need to customize the fast scrolling for an expandable listview. From what I've googled so far, I know that I can set a custom drawable to show instead of the default blue colored scrollbar that Android provides. But is there any way to display data on that scrollbar (Specifically the group position for the expandable listview, using a relative layout and thus completely making the default bar invisible). If not, I'll have to implement the entire functionality for fast scrolling myself, which is quite cumbersome. 
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If not, I'll have to implement the entire functionality for fast scrolling myself, `which is quite cumbersome` !!

Comment: What's wrong in that, I have already tried implementing it. It's **not easy handling pixel by pixel movement of listview**, and this I'm writing from my experience.

Comment: Your question history indicates otherwise

Comment: Doesn't matter, because I only ask very specific questions here, even this question has been asked after hours of digging on manually implementing the above. I find this as a platform to know something which is not pretty obvious on docs, or google. Just a suggestion, if you can't answer a query, try making a sensible comment.

Comment: Please refer [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for those links, but I've already asked several questions on SO, and many of them got upvoted too. I ask questions only after I try my best, and I don't intend to waste anyone's time. Still appreciate the time you spent on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewHolder concept for fast scrolling and smooth scrolling.

Offical docx.
[ListView Scrolling](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html),

here is nice exaplanation about ListView ViewHolder. http://blog.xebia.com/2013/07/22/viewholder-considered-harmful/